# Can bootstrap templates be used in asp.net html pages?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio-2015

I'm currently building a VB.net web API. I've downloaded a Bootstrap template and trying to apply it to my project. I've put in the css and js files in their respective folders. I've also changed the files directory URL in the template following the directory of those css and js in my project.

But when i run the project, its not working. The page looked as though i've not applied any templates at all. I realised from code samples and tutorials i've watched, they all used aspx(web forms). Is my page not displaying because i'm applying the template on a vbhtml page?

Before, i imported the css template like below:

```
<link href="~css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

**WORKING CODE**

I left out the '/' in between '~' and the file path. It should have been as shown below:

```
<link href="~/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Tips from Mark Fitzpatrick: Press F12 during your project execution to find out what's wrong/error in your page

Comment: If you open the browser console, do you see any errors? Like failure during loading of css/js? If not, it's probably that VB.net style overwrite Bootstrap styles.

Comment: Use the F12 developer tools and see if you have any errors. Open the networking tab of the tools and look to see if all the scripts and styles are being loaded. Bootstrap is simply CSS and JavaScript so it works fine with VS (to the point the default project templates now use it). Most likely you have a path issue where the files aren't exactly where the browser is expecting them and aren't loading.

Comment: @MarkFitzpatrick Thanks for the F12 tip! You're great! I didn't know i could check for errors that way. I've made a typo and missed '/' in between '~' and the file path. I only did ~path..no wonder it didn't work >.<

Comment: Can you please update the question with some codes (What you have done so far) ? @Nurul